# Get week days array based on week day number

Tags: javascript

For instance, if I pass a week number as 3, I would like the array to be sorted as

```
weekStartDayNumber = 3

weekdays = ['wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday']
```

If I pass week weekStartDayNumber as 7 I want the array to be sorted as follows

```
weekdays = ['sunday',...'saturday']
```

The array needs to be sorted based on the weekStartDayNumber.

```
function days(weekStartDayNumber) { //logic here}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array.slice()`:

```js
function arrangeDays(startNum) {
    let days = ['monday', 'tuesday','wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']
    let arrStart = days.slice(startNum-1)
    let arrEnd = days.slice(0, startNum-1)

    return arrStart.concat(arrEnd)
}

console.log(arrangeDays(3))
console.log(arrangeDays(7))
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const weekDays = ['monday', 'tuesday','wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']

const days = (n) =>
  // Splice will take out everything from where ever you want to start until 
  // the end of the array and remove that part from the original. So
  // weekdays only contains whatever is left. So simply add the rest
  // using concat
  weekDays.splice(n - 1, weekDays.length - n + 1).concat(weekDays);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const days = (n) => [...weekdays.slice(n-1), ...weekdays.slice(0, n-1)]
```

This should do what you need. A nice little ES6 one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

```
let a = function SortByDay(startNum) {
    let weekDays = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']
    return weekDays
        .slice(startNum - 1)
        .concat(weekDays
        .slice(0, startNum - 1));
};
```